# How is this message in the Review Queues generated?

Tags: discussion

I have been noticing this comment a lot and most of the time, different users post exactly the same comment. The comment goes:

> This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/405160)

It has a few hyperlinks (which I think is a bit time consuming to do manually). I'm wondering if this is generated somewhere I don't know. I read about the review queues in the help center but I may have missed it or information about it might not be present there.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Some one in software development of deign at StackExchange wrote it once, and it is used as a choice of one of the generic responses in a flag on answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment says, it's generated from the [Low Quality Posts Queue](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/). In that queue, simply click on Recommend Deletion (or Delete, for those with delete votes) and you'll get a pop up that allows you to select a reason for the post to be deleted. If you're the first one to choose the reason, then it posts a comment for you in your name. If you're not the first, it upvotes the existing comment for you.

This comment is special too, because it notifies the post author even after their post was deleted.

Comment: Thank you for the insight! :-)